# IIS total file size limit per user

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, ftp, iis-7, virtual-directory

I have a virtual directory shared among all users on an IIS 7 FTP server (they still have their private directories). I'll have to limit the maximum amount of files that each user may upload in this shared directory.

However, I can't seem to find any option for this. IIS is currently required to BE used for my task and we cannot switch to any other FTP server software.

Now my question is: Is it even possible to have such a limit shared across files per user or does IIS not support this?

Answer (score 0):

> However, I can't seem to find any option for this.

No, because this is not IIS job. IIS serves documents.

Set user quotas on the folder. Finished - the OS Has the functionality for this.

If you do not know about this....

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733029.aspx

explains it.